# having trouble in populating spinner from JSON because of delay in response

Tags: android, json

i am having trouble to load data from json object because response take its time and before respone come view is created and data is not loaded in spinner
can any one has better idea for this problem.

Comment: If you have done anything, post it.

Comment: You can do one thing. 
First make spinner invisble. And when response come (If you are using AsyncTaskthen on - onPost method) visible Spinner and notifyDataSetChanged to your adapter

Comment: set adapter to spinner only after you have the data

Comment: can you please tell what are you using for json request

Comment: m using volley for network communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it where i was getting wrong. i was assigning an empty array to spinner's Adapter because response took its time to get the data from server and before that i was assigning json array to my array "**mCategoriesNameArray**" i just shifted this array (which i was assigning to spinner's Adapter) to the response listener and it worked fine

mCatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, **mCategoriesNameArray**);

Answer (score 1):

you should post some code you have but but let me give you idea.

In Responce Listner parce the json object and the add the items to spinner .

and Call `notifyDatasetChanged()` of adapter class

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you can post a sample code of yours, It would very helpful for us to help you. But anyway try below.

Try:

```
private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
      //Your long waiting job goes here

       return resultJson
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String resultJson) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        // Populate your spinner
        populateSpinnerWith(resultJson);
    }
```

Usage:

```
FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask()
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```